# Do process supported by Java mean the same as process supported by the underlying OS?

Tags: java, process, multiprocessing

Java supports multiprocess via `Process`, `ProcessBuilder` and `Runtime.exec()`...

Do process supported by Java mean the same as process supported by the underlying OS?

Or is process supported by Java a different concept from process supported by the underlying OS?

Is there some mapping between processes supported by Java and processes supported by the underlying OS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the [official Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html):

> The `ProcessBuilder.start()` and `Runtime.exec` methods create a native process and return an instance of a subclass of `Process` that can be used to control the process and obtain information about it.

So yes, these represent native processes of the underlying OS.